# Apache2: Hosting Multiple Sites (Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2, systemd

I am new working with system.d and services on ubuntu/debian. I'm trying to serve multiple sites on the same **Apache2**.

```
viktor@viktor-i7-7700k:~$ ls -la /etc/apache2/
total 96
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root  4096 fev  3 16:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 133 root root 12288 fev  3 16:13 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  7224 ago 12 18:33 apache2.conf
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 fev  3 16:13 conf-available
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 fev  3 16:13 conf-enabled
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1782 jul 16  2019 envvars
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 31063 jul 16  2019 magic
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 fev  3 16:13 mods-available
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 fev  3 16:13 mods-enabled
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   320 jul 16  2019 ports.conf
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 fev  3 16:13 sites-available
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 fev  3 16:13 sites-enabled
```

I need to configure three instances of server to listen on ports 8081, 8082, and 8083 respectively. For example, on visiting h`ttp://host1.com:8081, http://host2.com:8082` and  `http://host3.com:8083` the HTML pages  are in var `/var/mysites/host1/index.html`, `/var/mysites/host2/index.html` and `/var/mysites/host3/index.html` respectively should be rendered by default. Also, we should be able to start, to stop and restart the apache serer using the following commands:

```
sudo apache2ctl-host1 start; sudo apache2ctl-host2 start; sudo apache2ctl-host1 start;
sudo apache2ctl-host1 stop; sudo apache2ctl-host2 stop; sudo apache2ctl-host1 stop;
sudo apache2ctl-host1 restart; sudo apache2ctl-host2 restart; sudo apache2ctl-host1 restart;
```

To test my instances, it was required these conditions:

The Apache2 webserver installation is verified by running the `dpkg --get-selections | grep apache2` command.

The server instances are started by running sudo `apache2ctl-host1 start`; sudo apache2ctl-host2 start; `sudo apache2ctl-host3 start`;

The port is verified by running the `sudo lsof -i:8081 | grep apache2`, `sudo lsof -i:8082 | grep apache2`and `sudo lsof -i:8083 | grep apache2` commands.

Th HTML conted is fetched by running the `curl host1.com:8081,curl host2.com:8082 and curl host3.com:8083` commands.

The page must not be a 403 or 404 error page, ie., the following commands must exit with non-zero code:

```
curl host1.com:8081 | grep 403\ Forbidden
curl host1.com:8082 | grep 403\ Forbidden
curl host1.com:8083 | grep 403\ Forbidden
curl host1.com:8081 | grep 404\ Not \ Found
curl host1.com:8082 | grep 404\ Not \ Found
curl host3.com:8083 | grep 404\ Not \ Found
```

Also, the  HTML files `/var/save/mysites/host1/index.html`, `/var/save/mysites/host2/index.html` and `/var/save/mysites/host3/index.html` and the rendered HTML files snhoud be exactly same.

Comment: Those are somewhat complicated requirements.  The normal pattern is to have one apache instance serve up multiple sites, and you can define the sites by setting up multiple config files in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. So you'd normally end up with 3 files in sites-enabled, like host1, host2, host3. However, setting up multiple apachectl commands really implies you need 3 apache instances and not one shared instance. This complicates things a bit.  Also, this is probably the wrong forum for it -- https://unix.stackexchange.com/ is for unix questions.  This forum is for programming questions.

Comment: @NicholasRees thanks, I will publish there

Answer (score 0):

You should just use one apache and configure it to listen on 3 (or more) different ports using the "listen" option:

```
Listen 10080
Listen 10443
Listen 20080
Listen 20443
```

Then you can configure any virtualhost you need, to respond on a specific port:

```
<Virtualhost *:10080>
  ServerName aDomain.com
  #Other conf
</virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:10443>
  ServerName anotherDomain.com
  #Other conf
</virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:20080>
  ServerName aThirdOne.Domain.io
  #Other conf
</virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:20443>
  ServerName another.Domainof.any.kind
  #Other conf
</virtualhost>
```

More details and configuration options can be found on the official documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: How do I create 3 services like these?
i.e:


`sudo apachec2ctl-host1 start; sudo apachec2ctl-host2 start; sudo apachec2ctl-host1 start;
sudo apachec2ctl-host1 stop; sudo apachec2ctl-host2 stop; sudo apachec2ctl-host1 stop;
sudo apachec2ctl-host1 restart; sudo apachec2ctl-host2 restart; sudo apachec2ctl-host1 restart;`

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/785431/creating-multiple-apache-instances-on-centos-7-systemd
https://opensource.com/article/20/12/multiple-service-instances-systemctl

Comment: thanks for help me to understand it